# Type error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'onclick' in package 'android'

Tags: android

This is my first apps, please help me to fix this

Type error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'onclick' in package 'android'

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onclick='buttonBtn'
    ></Button>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Change to: android:onClick='buttonBtn'

This Is Called click Event in Android Use it in Java file

public void buttonBtn(View view)
 { 
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Buttan Click", 1).show();
 }

Answer (score 0):

Change this to

```
 android:onclick='buttonBtn'
```

To

```
   android:onClick='buttonBtn'
```

c is  Capital not small

Since Android's XML parser is case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Change to:
`android:onClick='buttonBtn'`

and in your activity, do this:

```
public void buttonBtn(View view){ 
   //do button action here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is caused due to spelling mistake at

```
  android:onClick='buttonBtn'
```